# How to create custom Component without extra method in java?

Tags: java, swing

I have created custom class for Labels and it works fine but what i want is .
when  ever i create instance from that class  the label must be created without require extra returnable method .

look my code please

```
class  CustomLabel {

        private  JLabel customLabel;

         public  CustomLabel() {
                createLabel();
         }

         private  void createLabel() {
                customLabel = new JLabel("Label test");
         }

         /*
           i do not want to return this                 
          */
          public JLabel getLabel() {
                  return customLabel;
          }

}

class  Booter {

        /*
            calling customLabel
          */
         void createUI() {
                CustomLabel customLabel = new CustomLabel();

                 JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();

                 // this is not working
                 jPanel.add(customLabel);
                 // but if i call extra method that inside customLabel
                 // it works fine but i do not want it
                 jPanel.add(customLabel.getLabel());
                 //i need to do same like java defined component like.
                 JLabel label = new JLabel("Test2");
                 jPanel.add(label); // its is not required getLabel or others
           }
}
```

Comment: This is Swing, not JavaFX

Comment: This is overkill to create a class that is only for creating a label with static text. You can do the same thing with a single line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the class `JLabel` if you want to directly create it using its constructor:

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class CustomLabel extends JLabel {

    public CustomLabel(String text) {
        super(text);
    }
}
```

And then in your calling code, you can do this:

```
class Booter {

    void createUI() {
        CustomLabel customLabel = new CustomLabel("TEST TEXT");

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Test2");
        jPanel.add(customLabel);
        jPanel.add(label);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just extend JLabel

```
class  CustomLabel extends JLabel {
  public CustomLabel() {
    super("Label test");
  }
}

class  Booter{

                   /*
                   calling customLabel
                   */
                   void createUI(){
                       jPanel.add(new CustomLabel());


                   }
               }
```